# limit of a recurrence relation (defined in odd and even terms)

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, recurrence-relations

Let $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 2 $, and for $n=1,2,...$ following recurrence is defined,

$$x_{2n+1} = \frac{5x_{2n-1} + 2x_{2n}}{7} , x_{2n+2} = \frac{2x_{2n-1} + 5x_{2n}}{7}$$

I need to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ exists and also find the lim.

My attempt: I tried to look at the difference between consecutive terms but it didn't worked, could anyone suggest any hint on how should I proceed...

Comment: Perhaps write it in matrix form and diagonalize.

Comment: Do you know linear algebra? Because this can be written as a matrix product: $$\begin{pmatrix}x_{2n+1}\\x_{2n+2}\end{pmatrix}=A\begin{pmatrix}x_{2n-1}\\x_{2n-2}\end{pmatrix}$$ for a simple $A$, and you just need to figure out what $\lim_{n\to\infty} A^n$

Comment: It's actually pretty easy to conjecture the correct answer. Can you think of what it might be?  It is useful to notice that $x_{2n-1}+x_{2n}$ is constant...

Comment: A shortcut is to use the change of variables $$y_n=x_{2n}+x_{2n-1}\qquad z_n=x_{2n}-x_{2n-1}$$ then $$y_{n+1}=y_n\qquad z_{n+1}=az_n$$ with $$a=\frac37$$ hence $$y_n=y_1\qquad z_n=a^{n-1}z_1$$ thus one knows $$x_{2n}=\frac12(y_n+z_n)\qquad x_{2n-1}=\frac12(y_n-z_n)$$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews, I believe the equation you wanted may have been $$\begin{pmatrix}x_{2n+1}\\x_{2n+2}\end{pmatrix}=A\begin{pmatrix}x_{2n-1}\\x_{2n}\end{pmatrix}$$ Possibly?

Comment: Yeah, an off-by-one error. :) @JoDraX

Comment: Another approach: Prove that the sequence is contractive, so it has a limit. Use that $x_{2n-1}+x_{2n}$ is constant as commented by @ThomasAndrews. Then $x_{2n-1}+x_{2n}$ is constant $3$. So, the sequence $x_n$ converges to $3/2$ because $x_{2n-1}$ and $x_{2n}$ must have the same limits.

Comment: This is pretty much the same as @Did's.

Comment: @JoDraX I got the matrix $$A= \frac{1}{7} \begin{bmatrix}5&2\\2&5\end{bmatrix}$$, Also, $X_{n+1} = AX_n$, where $X_n = \left[\begin{array}{l} x_{2n-1}\\ x_{2n}\end{array}\right]$, So, the $lim x_n$ can be found using $\lim_\infty$ $A^n$, The $\lim $ $A^n$ is $0.5 I$ Hence, $\lim x_n = \frac{(x_1 + x_2)}{2}  = \frac{3}{2}$, Thanks for help!